# Can I Sous Vide a roasting joint?

Tags: beef, sous-vide

With the end of year Christmas shopping panic, the only beef joint I could get for Christmas day was a 1.6kg roasting joint. There is no other marking on the pack, so I assume this is either silverside, topside or salmon cut.

I was intending to sous vide this for 24 hours at 60C. Would I achieve better results following the instructions and cooking it in the oven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sous vide is an excellent method of cooking this type of meat. The best results will very much depend on the precise cut of the meat, the temperature used and the amount of fat and marbling.

I cooked this joint (which had very little connective tissue or fat) for 20 hours at 60C. The meat was tender, moist but not overly juicy and was somewhere between a medium and medium-well doneness. I had to split in into two pieces as the whole joint would not fit in a standard vacuum bag.

Guests all said it was the tastiest beef they had sampled in a long time.